# Page Layout issue in custom object

Tags: page-layout

On the detail page of a record, I clicked *edit layout*, added some fields and saved. However, I am not able to see the added fields in the layout. What might have gone wrong?

Comment: Please check field level security for newly added fields. Please check this link [Field-Level Security](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_fls.htm&type=0)  to set Field Level Security in salesforce

Comment: if you have recordtypes, check for appropriate layout

Comment: @Pragati Jain,,there an issuse with field level security.i enabled it,working fine.thanks